# HSL Lightness vs Eye sensitivity

Tags: human-biology, eyes, vision

In a monochromatic spectrum, is the human eye equally able to distinguish between lighter colors just as it is in distinguishing between darker colors? I mean is there really a linear relationship between the Lightness property in the HSL color model and the perceived brightness?

Comment: [Related question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/which-shades-hues-of-color-are-easiest-to-distinguish-for-humans)

Comment: I'm not sure this is really the best possible SE site for this question; my answer below, at least, has very little biology in it. There's no "Colorimetry Stack Exchange", but I'd think this would be on topic e.g. at [graphicdesign.SE]. Alas, they don't have MathJax... maybe [physics.SE] would be a better fit? Or [cogsci.SE]?

Answer (score 2):

No, the *L* axis in the [HSL color space](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) does not really correspond to [lightness](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightness_%28color%29) as perceived by the human eye, except in the very crudest sense that, for given values of the *H* and *S* components, increasing *L* produces an increase in the perceived lightness.

The *L* component of the standard HSL color space is simply calculated as the average of the lowest and the highest RGB component of the color (in whichever [RGB color space](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space) in being used): $$L = \frac{\min(R, G, B) + \max(R,G,B)}2$$

This definition alone should make it obvious that the *L* value *cannot* correspond to perceived lightness, since it completely ignores the middle one of the three RGB channels.  Thus, the color (*R*=0, *G*=0, *B*=1), i.e. pure $\color{#0000ff}{\rm blue}$, has exactly the same *L* value (0.5) as the color (*R*=0, *G*=1, *B*=1), i.e. $\color{#00ffff}{\rm cyan}$, yet it's obvious at a glance that the latter color is visually much brighter.

Indeed, the HSL color space doesn't even *try* to match the perceptual lightness of the colors; rather, the definition of the *L* channel is chosen because it has the convenient feature that it maps black to *L*=0, white to *L*=1, and all the six maximally saturated pure RGB colors (red, yellow, green, cyan, blue and magenta), despite their wide perceptual lightness differences, to *L*=0.5.

---

A much better approximation to the perceived lightness of a color is the [luma](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29) *Y*', which is defined as a weighted average of the RGB channels.  The precise weights depend on the definition and the RGB color space used, but a common choice (from [ITU-R Rec. 709](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709)) is: $$Y' = 0.2126\, R + 0.7152\, G + 0.0722\, B$$

The weighs are chosen to account for the different perceived lightness of the different RGB primary colors.  A striking feature is the that the green component alone accounts for over 70% of the luma, nearly ten times as much as the blue component.  Yet a visual comparison of $\color{#0000ff}{\rm 100\%\ blue}$ with $\color{#00ff00}{\rm 100\%\ green}$ does clearly confirm that this choice of weights is justified: the pure green appears *much* brighter than the blue, and almost as bright as the cyan (which is their sum) above.

---

However, the definition of the luma still ignores the non-linearity of both the standard RGB color spaces (such as [sRGB](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sRGB)) and the human eye.  While these two effects partly cancel out each other, allowing luma to be used as a reasonable approximation of perceptual lightness, for truly accurate results they need to be accounted for.  This involves several steps:

1. Convert the RGB color into a linear color space.  For sRGB, the following [formula](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) may be used: $R_L = f(R), G_L = f(G), B_L = f(B)$, where: $$f(C) = \begin{cases}C / 12.92 & \text{if } 0 \le C \le 0.04045 \\ ((C + 0.055) / 1.055)^{2.4} & \text{if }  0.04045 < C \le 1 \end{cases}$$ (Here, $R$, $G$ and $B$ are the sRGB component values, and $R_L$, $G_L$ and $B_L$ the linear ones, both scaled to the range from 0.0 to 1.0.)  Alternatively, a very close approximation to the formula above is given by simple [gamma-expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) with $\gamma = 2.2$: $f(C) = C^{2.2}$.
2. Calculate the [relative luminance](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_%28relative%29) as a weighted average of the linear RGB component values: $$Y = 0.2126\, R_L + 0.7152\, G_L + 0.0722\, B_L$$ (The weights are exactly the same as for the luma formula above, because that's where they come from; the luma calculation just blindly applies them to the gamma-compressed RGB values.)
3. Convert the relative luminance value into an approximation of the percieved lightness, using something like the [CIELAB](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB) formula: $\ell^* = 1.16\, g(Y) - 0.16$, where: $$g(Y) = \begin{cases} \tfrac13 \left(\tfrac{29}{6}\right)^2 Y + \tfrac{4}{29} & \text{if } 0 \le Y \le \left(\tfrac{6}{29}\right)^3\\ Y^{1/3} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ (Note: In the CIELAB standard, the $L^*$ value ranges from 0 to 100, but for the sake of consistency, in the formula above I chose to define $\ell^* = L^* / 100$, so that its range is also from 0 to 1.)